# Twilio phone number for Whatsapp

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I want to buy a number on Twilio to use with Whatsapp chat.  Many of the numbers has only a "voice" option (and not SMS, MMS, etc.).

Can one also use this number or is Whatsapp by default an SMS?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

This support article will help:

[Which Twilio Phone Numbers are Compatible with WhatsApp?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026678054-Which-Twilio-Phone-Numbers-are-Compatible-with-WhatsApp-)

Alan